# How to change the width of the dropdown option box in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

**Problem:**

I have created select in my angular application. I want to change the width of the option dropdown.

This is my HTML code.

```
<select class="myselct" id="myselct">
  <option value="1">selct option1</option>
  <option value="1">selct option1</option>
  <option value="1">selct option1</option>
</select>
```

This is my CSS code.

```
#myselct {
  width: 8px;
}

#myselct option {
  width: 8px !important;
}
```

I tried lot to find out a solution do this. But was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem ? I can see its working fine in my stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-width

Comment: @Akhil I think they are asking a question about the option width being a different size than the select width

Comment: @rhavelka But we can see the user is trying to set the same width of 8px for both select and option from the above CSS code block

Comment: Browsers do not have a lot of control over windowed elements.

Comment: @Akhil I wasn't looking too close at their css. When i looked at your stackblitz and saw 250, I was thinking that's what the user had for their `#mySelect`

Comment: @rhavelka aww ok. 8px was too small that's why I gave 250px